# How to pass a variable task_ids to a xcom.pull in Airflow?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

Sometimes I find it handy to create tasks using a loop.

Below is an example of a SqoopOperator of which I use the xcom value from the previous PythonOperator in the where clause. I am trying to use a variable `get_delivery_sqn_task_id` to access the correct xcom value `ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=get_delivery_sqn_task_id` , however this does not work (returns ()).

I can take everything out of the loop, but this makes the code quite ugly I think. Is there an elegant solution to have a variable task_ids to retrieve xcom values? I guess otherwise the best solution is using the Airflow Variables.

```
for table in tables:
    
    get_delivery_sqn_task_id ='get_delivery_sqn_'+ table 
    
    get_delivery_sqn_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id = get_delivery_sqn_task_id,
        python_callable = get_delivery_sqn,
        op_kwargs = {
            'table_name': table
            },
        provide_context = True,
        dag = dag
    )
    
    sqoop_operator_task = SqoopOperator(
        task_id = "sqoop_"+table,
        conn_id = "DWDH_PROD",
        table = table,
        cmd_type = "import",
        target_dir = "/sourcedata/sqoop_tmp/"+table,
        num_mappers = 1,
        where = "delivery_sqn > {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=get_delivery_sqn_task_id, key='return_value') }}",
        dag = dag
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
"delivery_sqn > {{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids={}, key='return_value') }}}}".format(get_delivery_sqn_task_id)
```

Comment: Thanks Elad! Only missing the single quotes to make the task_ids a string but this works!
`f"delivery_sqn > {{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='{get_delivery_sqn_task_id}', key='return_value') }}}}"`